Sending Record File as attachment in Salesforce
Trying to send latest file as attachment in email , but File Content is getting empty
   
    <messaging:attachment filename="{!latestFileName}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!latestFileBlob}" escape="false"/>
    </messaging:attachment> 
</apex:component> 

This Component I m calling in my visual force email template.
and below is my controller
    public Blob latestFileBlob { get; private set; }
    public String latestFileName { get; private set; }
    private String recordId;

    public SendLatestContentController() {
        // Retrieve the record Id from the standard controller
        recordId = '006VB000003QJLSYA4';

        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId 
                                              FROM ContentDocumentLink 
                                              WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId
                                              ORDER BY SystemModstamp DESC 
                                              LIMIT 1];
        if (!cdlList.isEmpty()) {       
            List<ContentVersion> cvList = [SELECT VersionData, Title, FileExtension, FileType 
                                           FROM ContentVersion 
                                           WHERE ContentDocumentId = :cdlList[0].ContentDocumentId 
                                           AND IsLatest = true 
                                           LIMIT 1];            
            if (!cvList.isEmpty()) {
                latestFileBlob = cvList[0].VersionData;
                latestFileName = cvList[0].Title + '.' + cvList[0].FileExtension;
                System.debug('Blob data%%%%' + latestFileBlob);
            }
        }
    }
}

Getting correct file name but content is empty
